# having issue passing multiselect as a query param

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Guys I am stuck on this issue for a few days now. When I pass regular select options as a parameter everything is working as expected  but when I pass multiselect checkboxes as a param its not working. I tested with some other html elements like input boxes and everything works as it should be only not working for multiselect. I think there is some issues with my jQuery code for multiselect, can you guys please have a look at it. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```js
function sendUrlToController(){

  //this works perfectly
  $('.searchMenu').find('tr').find('td').find('select').each(function(){
      sendURLParam($(this));
  }
  
  
  //this is not working
    $('.searchMenu').find('tr').find('td').find("#stuCourses input[aria-selected='true']").each(function(){
    sendURLParam($(this));
    }

}

function sendURLParam(passedParams){
  
  //binds passed param and sends to controller as query param

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<Table class="searchMenu">
<tr>
<td>
<select id="stuName">
    <option >Select one</option>
    <option >${studentName}</option>
</select>
</td>

<td >
<t:multiselect
id="stuCourses"
items="${courses}"
itemLabel="keyValue"
itemValue="keyValue"
selectedList="0"/>
</td>
<tr>
</Table
```

Comment: What is the multiselect plugin you used? sharing generated HTML will help you to get an answer

Comment: @ChamikaSandamal its a  jquery multiselect plugin, I can't share all the code as it is too long but I know I have issue in this $('.searchMenu').find('tr').find('td').find("#stuCourses input[aria-selected='true']").each(function(), just don't know how to fix it